# Making a clock in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy, and I'm trying to get a better handle on Events, as well as a few basics of the framework.

For that purpose, can anyone provide the code for a simple clock implemented in Kivy, which shows the current time, and updates every second?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's an extremely simple clock:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

import time

class IncrediblyCrudeClock(Label):
    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = time.asctime()

class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        crudeclock = IncrediblyCrudeClock()
        Clock.schedule_interval(crudeclock.update, 1)
        return crudeclock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```

[image: incredibly crude clock]

Answer (score 50):

What about a simple graphical one:

[image]
**EDIT (12.02.2022)**: Refactored the whole code to make it more readable

```py
import collections
import datetime
import math

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line

Builder.load_string('''
<MyClockWidget>:
    on_pos: self.update_clock()
    on_size: self.update_clock()
    FloatLayout
        id: face
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        size: 0.9*min(root.size), 0.9*min(root.size)
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    FloatLayout
        id: hands
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        size: 0.9*min(root.size), 0.9*min(root.size)
''')

Position = collections.namedtuple('Position', 'x y')


class MyClockWidget(FloatLayout):
    def on_parent(self, myclock, parent):
        """
        Add number labels when added in widget hierarchy
        """
        for i in range(1, 13):
            number = Label(
                text=str(i),
                pos_hint={
                    # pos_hint is a fraction in range (0, 1)
                    "center_x": 0.5 + 0.45*math.sin(2 * math.pi * i/12),
                    "center_y": 0.5 + 0.45*math.cos(2 * math.pi * i/12),
                }
            )
            self.ids["face"].add_widget(number)

    def position_on_clock(self, fraction, length):
        """
        Calculate position in the clock using trygonometric functions
        """
        center_x = self.size[0]/2
        center_y = self.size[1]/2
        return Position(
            center_x + length * math.sin(2 * math.pi * fraction),
            center_y + length * math.cos(2 * math.pi * fraction),
        )

    def update_clock(self, *args):
        """
        Redraw clock hands
        """
        time = datetime.datetime.now()
        hands = self.ids["hands"]
        seconds_hand = self.position_on_clock(time.second/60, length=0.45*hands.size[0])
        minutes_hand = self.position_on_clock(time.minute/60+time.second/3600, length=0.40*hands.size[0])
        hours_hand = self.position_on_clock(time.hour/12 + time.minute/720, length=0.35*hands.size[0])

        hands.canvas.clear()
        with hands.canvas:
            Color(0.2, 0.5, 0.2)
            Line(points=[hands.center_x, hands.center_y, seconds_hand.x, seconds_hand.y], width=1, cap="round")
            Color(0.3, 0.6, 0.3)
            Line(points=[hands.center_x, hands.center_y, minutes_hand.x, minutes_hand.y], width=2, cap="round")
            Color(0.4, 0.7, 0.4)
            Line(points=[hands.center_x, hands.center_y, hours_hand.x, hours_hand.y], width=3, cap="round")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        clock_widget = MyClockWidget()
        # update initially, just after construction of the widget is complete
        Clock.schedule_once(clock_widget.update_clock, 0)
        # then update every second
        Clock.schedule_interval(clock_widget.update_clock, 1)
        return clock_widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Old answer**:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from math import cos, sin, pi
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

import datetime

kv = '''
#:import math math

[ClockNumber@Label]:
    text: str(ctx.i)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5+0.42*math.sin(math.pi/6*(ctx.i-12)), "center_y": 0.5+0.42*math.cos(math.pi/6*(ctx.i-12))}
    font_size: self.height/16

<MyClockWidget>:
    face: face
    ticks: ticks
    FloatLayout:
        id: face
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        size: 0.9*min(root.size), 0.9*min(root.size)
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size     
                pos: self.pos
        ClockNumber:
            i: 1
        ClockNumber:
            i: 2
        ClockNumber:
            i: 3
        ClockNumber:
            i: 4
        ClockNumber:
            i: 5
        ClockNumber:
            i: 6
        ClockNumber:
            i: 7
        ClockNumber:
            i: 8
        ClockNumber:
            i: 9
        ClockNumber:
            i: 10
        ClockNumber:
            i: 11
        ClockNumber:
            i: 12
    Ticks:
        id: ticks
        r: min(root.size)*0.9/2
'''
Builder.load_string(kv)

class MyClockWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Ticks(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Ticks, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_clock)
        self.bind(size=self.update_clock)

    def update_clock(self, *args):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            time = datetime.datetime.now()
            Color(0.2, 0.5, 0.2)
            Line(points=[self.center_x, self.center_y, self.center_x+0.8*self.r*sin(pi/30*time.second), self.center_y+0.8*self.r*cos(pi/30*time.second)], width=1, cap="round")
            Color(0.3, 0.6, 0.3)
            Line(points=[self.center_x, self.center_y, self.center_x+0.7*self.r*sin(pi/30*time.minute), self.center_y+0.7*self.r*cos(pi/30*time.minute)], width=2, cap="round")
            Color(0.4, 0.7, 0.4)
            th = time.hour*60 + time.minute
            Line(points=[self.center_x, self.center_y, self.center_x+0.5*self.r*sin(pi/360*th), self.center_y+0.5*self.r*cos(pi/360*th)], width=3, cap="round")

class MyClockApp(App):
    def build(self):
        clock = MyClockWidget()
        Clock.schedule_interval(clock.ticks.update_clock, 1)
        return clock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClockApp().run()
```

Comment: I'm fascinated with your example. (I'm also new in Kivy)
Few things are unclear for me.
You instantiating clock = MyClockWidget()
And MyClockWidget has no implemethation it only inherit FloatLayout.
But next line you have 
Clock.schedule_interval(clock.ticks.update_clock, 1)
How come clock has property ticks?
Has it something to do with "    ticks: ticks" in your kv file?
But honestly what is ticks: ticks I also do not understand :)

And another thing I don't get is sort of bigger picture.
Why it couldn't be in form on a one widget/class which could be added to anywhere?

Comment: @user2997497 originally it was supposed to be a quick and dirty example, but it somehow amassed a lot of votes after nine years on Stack Overflow. I don't consider this code to be particularly pretty and I believe it's rather contrived example to start learning the framework from. Anyway, `Clock` is internal Kivy's [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) class and `clock` (note it's not capitalized) is a name of variable to hold the widget. So `Clock.schedule_interval(clock.ticks.update_clock, 1)` calls Kivy's scheduler to call `update_clock` every second to draw hands.

Comment: And `Ticks` should be rather named `Hands` because it holds them (my English failed me back then as I am not a native speaker). I added this widget to `MyClockWidget` in kv layout and this `ticks: ticks` thing allows me to reference it outside the code. I think you can skip it and just `call clock.ids['ticks']` to get into this variable in modern Kivy code (I think it was a bit more convoluted back then).

Comment: @user2997497 I refactored the entire example, I hope it's more readable now