# Breaking Main loop in kivy (Freezing Screen)

Tags: android, python-2.7, loops, kivy

I got and issue that when i bind a function with an button that works good but when i bind a function which has a infinite loop in it so screen freezes and other button do not works as example below....please give me solution to break that loop using another button..

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

class APPLICATION_START(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buone = Button(text="Start Loop",pos=(0,180),size=(470,90),size_hint=(None,None))
        self.logi.bind(on_release=self.loooop)
        self.exitbtn = Button(text="exit",pos=(0,90),size=(235,70),size_hint=(None,None))
        self.exitbtn.bind(on_press=exit)

    def loooop(self,instance):
        while True:
            # do any Activity

        #I want to break this loop when someone press on exit button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return APPLICATION_START()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I know little about threads but instead of using a loop create a new thread to do that.

Comment: How?...can give example code

Comment: Why would you want to use an infinite loop?

Comment: Its an email bomb app....so in infinite loop it keep sending emails untill user do not stop the app

Answer (score 1):

The gui can't update until your function returns, which it doesn't.

Either use a thread for your task, or if it is composed of many repetitions of a short task you can do `Clock.schedule_interval(your_function, some_timestep)` to run it repeatedly.

Comment: Button.bind(on_press= Clock.schedule_interval(your_function, some_timestep)  is this right??

Comment: No. Button.bind takes a function as the argument, you must create a function that adds the scheduled task to the clock.

Comment: `some_function():`
 `Clock.schedule_interval(your_function, some_timestep)`


is this right?

Comment: How about posting your attempt in your original post

Comment: `class main_rootApp(App):
    
        time = StringProperty()
        def update(self,*args):
            self.time = str(time.asctime())
        
        def build(self):
            self.title = "Multipurpose Application"
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1)
            return main_root()`

This is an example of an self updating clock.

Comment: Post it in the original post where the formatting can be correct

Comment: Have a look at the documentation and also visit this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923321/making-a-clock-in-kivy

Comment: I figured out thtat I have to use update GUI ... but when I use clock.interval app just crash...now what i have to do?please help