# How to add an image and clock to a kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to implement the template of the [ComicCreator](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/Application-Development/9781785286926/1/ch01lvl1sec13/Our%20project%20%20Comic%20Creator) GUI sample as a template for my own project. The [code](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/Application-Development/9781785286926/1/ch01lvl1sec13/Our%20project%20%20Comic%20Creator) is easy to follow, but I want to change the [`toolbox.kv`](https://github.com/robertour/kivy-book-examples/blob/master/Chapter_01_code/07%20-%20project%20interface/toolbox.kv) to look something like:

[image]

**Q:** How would I be able to append a logo, instead of the buttons currently there, and also have the current date time display (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM) shown perpetually.And lastly add a string `NYC, New York, USA`, all underneath each other as in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some playing arround with BoxLayout's and Image or AsyncImage if your image is from the web.

So the python code could look like this.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    your_time = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.padding = 10
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_time, 0.1)    

    def set_time(self,dt):
        self.your_time = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

And kv file look like this.

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10,10,10,0
        orientation: "horizontal"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 0.3,1
            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            AsyncImage
                source: 'http://lmsotfy.com/so.png'
            Label:
                size_hint: 1,0.3
                text: root.your_time
                color: [0,0,0,1]
            Label:
                size_hint: 1,0.3
                text: "NYC, New York, USA"
                color: [0,0,0,1]

        Button:
            text: ""

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10,10,10,0
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 1,0.3
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Button:
            text: "Clear"
        Button:
            text: "Remove"
        Button:
            text: "Group"
        Button:
            text: "Color"
        Button:
            text: "Gestures"

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10,10,10,10
        size_hint: 1,0.3
        Button:
            text: "Total figures: 1          Kivy Started"
```

This will look like this:

[image: kivy app]

Comment: thanks for that, my question was how would I be able print the _current_ time not just  "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM",

Comment: @3kstc ok where do you get the timevariable?

Comment: that's my key problem - despite reading various [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923321/making-a-clock-in-kivy), I just don't understand how to implement it into my code.

Comment: @3kstc Updated. Think that is what you want

Comment: @3kstc will you accept this answer :) , or are you seeking something else?

Comment: Actually, I have one more [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388782/how-to-change-a-space-when-a-button-is-pressed-with-kivy) about kivy....

Comment: @3kstc ok bring it on :)

Comment: any luck with my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388782/how-to-change-a-space-when-a-button-is-pressed-with-kivy/38391384#38391384) and an example on how to implement it into the code?