# How to connect my Kivy code to MySql database?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create an application that takes login from user and sends data to mysql database but don't know how to edit my code for it. Need help with it. Also, what I'm trying to creating is an application for speech to text translation. Currently my code is switching to the next screen but have to take speech input from user. How can I do it?

I've watched some tutorials but they are not applicable with my code

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Builder.load_string("""


""")

class Rootwidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SigninWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def validate_user(self):
        user = self.ids.username_field
        pwd = self.ids.pwd_field
        info = self.ids.info

        uname = user.text
        passw = pwd.text

        if uname == '' or passw == '':
            info.text = '[color=#FF0000]username and/ or password required[/color]'
        else:
            if uname == 'admin' and passw == 'admin':
                info.text = '[color=#00FF00]Logged In successfully![/color]'
                App.get_running_app().root.current = "SignedIn"
            else:
                info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Invalid Username and/or Password[/color]'

class SigninApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Rootwidget()

if __name__=="__main__":
    sa = SigninApp()
    sa.run()
```

**.kv file**

```
<Rootwidget>:
    Screen:
        name: "SignIn"
        SigninWindow:
    Screen:
        name: "SignedIn"
        Label:
            text: "You have signed in."


<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 16

<SigninWindow>:
    id: main_win
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        BorderImage:
            source: 'E:\pythonpics/blu2.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (.06, .45, .45, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Label:
            text: "Hello! Dear User Please Sign In"
            bold: True
            size_hint_x: .9

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: main_win.space_x, 10
        #spacing: 20
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100

            Label:
                id: info
                text: ''
                markup: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 20
            TextInput:
                id: username_field
                hint_text: "Username"
                multiline: False
                focus: True
                on_text_validate: pwd_field.focus = True
            TextInput:
                id: pwd_field
                hint_text: "Password"
                multiline: False
                password: True
                on_text_validate: root.validate_user()
        Label:
            id: sp
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
        Button:
            text: "Sign In"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
            background_color: (.06,.45,.45, 1)
            background_normal: ''
            on_release: root.validate_user()

        Label:
            id: sp2
```

The code should be able to take user data and save in the mysql database

Answer (score 1):

First install mysql-connector with pip in linux

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Then import that library

```
import mysql.connector
```

Later create a dictionary with your database credentials like this

```
config = {'user': 'insert_user',
          'password': 'insert_password',
          'host': '000.000.000.000',
          'database': 'insert_database_name',
          'raise_on_warnings': True}
```

Then create a class that has all the queries and structure to connect mysql databases

```
class mydatabase:

        def __init__(self):
            self.db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
            self.c = self.db.cursor()

        def get_rows(self):
            # a,b,c,d depence of your database structure and tables
            # use the query example below, query needs parenthesis obligated

            query=('SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE({}='{}')'.format("a","b","c","d"))
            self.c.execute(query)
            return self.c.fetchall()
```

And Finally, run this script anywhere to run a query.

```
db_connection=mydatabase()
db_answer=db_connection.get_rows()
```

Notes: Adapted from [el3ien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781117/retrieving-mysql-with-kivy) because he's using other database library