# How can I put one label with time on all of my screens

Tags: python, kivy

I'm starting with kivy and have some question. I'm have code with couple screens and buttons. How can I put one label with time or something like that on all of my screens? In the below code I created a screens but i don't wanna put 3 separate labels on the individual screens

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<StartScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Start >'
            size_hint_y: None
            hight: '40dp'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'

<SecondScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Test2'
            size_hint_y: None
            hight: '40dp'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'end'

<EndScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Test3'
            size_hint_y: None
            hight: '40dp'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'start'
""")

#declarate both screens
class StartScreen(Screen):
        pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
        pass

class EndScreen(Screen):
        pass

#create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(StartScreen(name='start'))
sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
sm.add_widget(EndScreen(name='end'))

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18926863/6646710

The code below defines a label which displays the time.

```
import time

class IncrediblyCrudeClock(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(IncrediblyCrudeClock, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = time.asctime()
```

The update function gets the current time from the python `time` module. The time is used to update the `text` property of the label. In the `init` method, the `clock` module is used to schedule calls to this update function each second.

---

Next I added this Label to all your kivy screens inside the kv string.

```
<StartScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Start >'
            size_hint_y: None
            hight: '40dp'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'
        IncrediblyCrudeClock:

<SecondScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Test2'
            size_hint_y: None
            hight: '40dp'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'end'
        IncrediblyCrudeClock:

<EndScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Test3'
            size_hint_y: None
            hight: '40dp'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'start'
        IncrediblyCrudeClock:
```

The final result looks like that [image]