# Kivy cursor black background

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am using Kivy with python for my app.
But there is black background on my cursor on Kivy window.

[image]

How can I fix it ?

I am using python3 on OSX

> UPDATE

I have same issue with hello world application too.

> When mouse stays at same position about 10 seconds, black background disappears, but when leaving and entering again, same problem occures

Comment: Can you reproduce it with ["Hello world"](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#create-an-application) application?

Comment: Sure. There is same problem too. I updated question, please review

Comment: you're using stable Kivy release? If yes, any chance you can test if reproducible on master: `pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip` ?

Comment: Ok Now I will try this way. 
And I also have another issue. Assume I have some functions (f1 ... fn). When I call all them and after each call change kivy label.text, all changes applied in window when all functions called. 
I want to log each event on window. How to do it ?

Comment: it happens because your functions and Kivy graphic event loop leave in same thread. You need either to call your functions in different thread or call with a bit delay using [Clock's methods](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) to leave event loop time to process changes. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18926863/1113207) example, pay attention to `Clock.schedule_interval` method.

Comment: Same here. Did you fix it?

Comment: Yes. fixed. Will write answer here. @KonradHałas please find answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many retries I figured out the problem.
As @Mikhail Gerasimov said, it was thread issue. H had lot of calculations in main thread (it takes over 10s).

After moving it to another thread, and let main thread empty, the problem with black background fixed.

Also I moved Kivy updates to another thread